# How can I run a process, wait for it to idle and then kill it from a windows batch file.

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, process

Is there any way to run an application from a batch (bat) file, for example notepad.exe, wait for the notepad window to idle (finish loading) and than immediately kill it? It is very easy to do this in c#, here is a c# example to further illustrate what i need to do:

```
process = Process.Start(processFullPath);
process.WaitForInputIdle();
process.Kill();
```

**This needs to be very accurate as it will be used to measure the application loading time.** I will much prefer to do it directly from a batch file and not to use third parties like autoit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found a workaround using powershell which I can execute like a batch file from command line. It will look something like the 
following code in a *.ps1 file:

```
Write-Host "Starting"
$p = Start-Process notepad -passThru
$p.WaitForInputIdle()
$p.Kill()
Write-Host "End"
```